# From LatexDraw to Overleaf

Tags: pstricks, code, overleaf

how can i use LateXDraw PST code on Overleaf? I copied the code but when I tried to compile to pdf nothing happens. This is the code generated from LateXDraw that I copied on Overleaf....what is wrong?

```
    % \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
% \usepackage{epsfig}
% \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
% \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
% \usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
% \usepackage{etoolbox} % For spaces in paths
% \makeatletter % For spaces in paths
% \patchcmd\Gread@eps{\@inputcheck#1 }{\@inputcheck"#1"\relax}{}{}
% \makeatother
% % User Packages:
% 
% 

\psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.5971154)(0.39423096,1.5971154)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.4](0.19711548,1.4000001)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.4](0.19711548,-1.4)
\end{pspicture}
}
```

Comment: `pdflatex` cannot make the computations required  by postscript. The simplest is to compile with `xelatex`,  using the switch `-shell-escape`. Other than that, you can follow the old way: `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf`.

Comment: it's too complicated for me to be honest....can you recommend me a good program to draw graphs, arrows, figures, diagrams etc... that can elaborate a code for overleaf???

Comment: Sorry, I mainly code by hand, mainly with `pstricks`, and sometimes with `tikz`. But that shouldn't be as complicated as you think. I don't know overleaf, but I think it must not be difficult to add a switch to the compiler. For commutative diagrams, you can look at `tikz-cd`.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ as @Bernard says, setting your compiler to XeLaTeX should work. You can refer to this page for the steps: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Choosing_a_LaTeX_Compiler